# Electric displacement clarification

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, dielectric, dipole-moment

I'm reading Griffiths E&M book and I just need some clarification about the electric displacement $\mathbf{D}$ given by $$\mathbf{D}=\epsilon_0\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{P}$$ where $\mathbf{E}$ is the electric field and $\mathbf{P}$ is my dipole moment per unit volume. Gauss's law in integral form then states $$\iint_{\partial s}\mathbf{D}\cdot d\mathbf{A}=Q_{free}$$
He later claims that we can not always simply draw up a Gaussian surface to solve for $\mathbf{D}$ given that $\nabla\times\mathbf{D}=\nabla\times\mathbf{P}$, which is not necessarily zero. My question is why does the non-zero curl of $\mathbf{D}$ mean that we can not rely on symmetry to draw up Gaussian surfaces and find $\mathbf{D}$ easily? Does a non-zero curl imply non-symmetric fields?

Answer (score 0):

A nonzero Curl of $\bf{P}$ implies that the curl of $\bf{D}$ is also nonzero, since
$$
\nabla \times \bf{D} = \nabla \times \bf{P}
$$
which means that the components parallel to the Gaussian surface are not guaranteed to be zero, and therefore you cannot calculate the field $\bf{D}$ that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a Gaussian surface that allows finding $\vec{D}$ from Gauss's theorem, then knowledge of the free charges is indeed enough to find $\vec{D}$.
But these cases of very strong symmetry are very rare.

In the general case, when Gauss's theorem alone is not sufficient, **the vector $\vec{D}$ does not only depend on the free charges.** This is the point on which Griffith's text wants to insist. In particular, as Griffith points out, there is no "Coulomb's law" which would make it possible to find $\vec{D}$ by an integration when we know the distribution of free charges.

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the displacement (or any smooth vector field) can be separated into a part that has a divergence but no curl and a part that has curl and no divergence (known as [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition)). i.e.
$$ \vec{D} = \vec{D}_1 + \vec{D}_2 $$
where
$$\nabla \times \vec{D}_1 = 0, \ \ \ \nabla \cdot \vec{D}_2 = 0 $$
and thus
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{D}=\nabla \cdot \vec{D}_1, \ \ \ \nabla \times \vec{D} = \nabla \times \vec{D}_2\ .$$

Gauss's law, where the closed surface integral of the displacement equals the volume integral of its divergence, can only tell you about $\vec{D_1}$, since $\vec{D}_2$ contributes nothing to the divergence of $\vec{D}$. But for $\vec{D}_1$ to represent **all** of $\vec{D}$ implies that $\vec{D}_2=0$ and hence $\nabla \times \vec{D} = 0$.

To put it another way, if the curl of $\vec{D}$ is non-zero, which would be the case if $\nabla \times \vec{P}\neq 0$, then it implies that $\vec{D}_2 \neq 0$ and so Gauss's law, which only tells you about $\vec{D}_1$ cannot give you the total D-field.